# Is there a way to change the color of unused variables for Go in VS Code?

Tags: go, visual-studio-code

I understand the reasoning behind why unused variables is a compile-time error (not a warning).
However, having a red-line error for EVERY new variable declaration does break my workflow.
Is there a way to make gopls/vscode play together so that I get different formatting for this error - yellow line, gray line, grayed out variable name etc?

Comment: It's not a VS code thing. It is the standard Golang toolchain

Comment: So VS Code cannot intercept that it is Unusedvar error and treat this type of error differently? Doesn't seem that difficult.

Comment: vscode-go extension does not support custom severity mapping. Someday one may consider feature like "python.analysis.diagnosticSeverityOverrides". However, I am not sure what kind of workflow is broken by the red-line error (that kindly tells the truth - your program is not in a buildable state).

Comment: as it happens while you're typing in new code you declare a variable and before you get to use it, you get a distracting bright red underline. as a newbie golang person I start thinking "oh, what did I do wrong now." so I stop typing, hover over and see it's just a meaningless error that would have gone away if I'd just kept typing.